# Como testar uma função em react?

Tags: react, testes-de-unidade

Tenho um componente em react com varias funções e quero testar apenas uma, só que não consigo puxar essa função no jast e React Testing Library.

Eu tentei fazer dessa forma mas não deu certo, ele retorna erro.

App.js

```
function somar(x, y) {
  return x + y
}
```

App.test.js

```
import { render, screen } from '@testing-library/react';
import App from './App';

test('somar', () => {
  render(<App />);
  const funcaoSoma = somar(10, 10);
  expect(funcaoSoma).toEqual(20);
});
```

Comment: Ele retorna um erro de montagem ou erro de teste? Qual a mensagem de erro completa?

Comment: O erro é que ele não consegue encontrar a função somar, não estou conseguindo buscar a função que está dentro de um componente funcional do React

Comment: Como exportou a função e como a importou?

Comment: Eu exportei o componente App ( export default App ). Dentro desse componente tem varias funções e quero exportar elas para testar.  No arquivo de teste não consigo acessar essas funções.

Comment: *"....Eu exportei o componente App...."*, se você só fala o que fez mas não mostra vai continuar igual.

Comment: Eu mostrei como fiz no código que está na pergunta. Eu quero exportar a função somar, já coloquei export na frente da função ( export function somar ), mas o React mostra um erro, então quero saber se tem alguma forma de exportar uma função que está dentro de um componente React.

Comment: To perdendo tempo, onde está a declaração `export {somar};` no App.js e onde está a declaração `import {somar} from './App';` no App.test.js? Onde está a mensagem de erro completa? Nós não somos funcionários do site, somos um bando de pessoas que usam o horário de almoço e as folgas do café para ajudar aos outros.

Answer (score -2):

Considerando o código do seu test, você pode colocar a função `somar()` fora do escopo do componente e exportar, por exemplo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Assim, você consegue importar a função `somar()` no test e ele funcionará:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Código completo: https://codesandbox.io/s/dazzling-surf-8543yg?file=/src/App.test.js

Comment: Negativar sem escrever o motivo não é justo. Apresentei uma resposta que resolve o questionamento do Miguel. O que está errado aqui?